# Could not access Minikube(v1.18.1) Ingress on Docker-Driver Windows 10

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress, tunnel

My issue is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275458/could-not-access-kubernetes-ingress-in-browser-on-windows-home-with-minikube). But replication the question again for your reference::

I am facing the problem which is that I could not access the Minikube Ingress on the Browser using it's IP. I have installed Minikube on Windows 10 Home, and starting the minikube with docker driver(`minikube start --driver=docker`).

> **System info:**
>
> Windows 10 Home
>
> Minikube(v1.18.1)
>
> Docker(driver for minikube) - Docker
> engine version 20.10.5

I am following this official document - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

First I created the deployment by running this below command on Minikube.

`kubectl create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0`

The deployment get created which can be seen on the below image: enter image description here

[image]

Next, I exposed the deployment that I created above. For this I ran the below command.

`kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080`

This created a service which can be seen by running the below command:

`kubectl get service web`
The screenshot of the service is shown below:
[image]

3. I can now able to visit the service on the browser by running the below command:

`minikube service web`

In the below screenshot you can see I am able to view it on the browser.

[image]

4. Next, I created an Ingress by running the below command:

`kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml`

The ingress gets created and I can verify it by running the below command:

`kubectl get ingress`
The screenshot for this is given below:
[image]

The ingress ip is listed as 192.168.49.2. So that means if I should open it in the browser then it should open, but unfortunately not. It is showing site can't be reached. See the below screenshot.

[image]

What is the problem. Please provide me a solution for it?

I also added the mappings on etc\hosts file.

`192.168.49.2 hello-world.info`

Then I also tried opening hello-world.info on the browser but no luck.

In the below picture I have done ping to hello-world.info which is going to IP address 192.168.49.2. This shows etc\hosts mapping is correct:

[image]

I also did curl to minikube ip and to hello-world.info and both get timeout. See below image:

[image]

The `kubectl describe services web` provides the following details:

```
Name:                     web
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=web
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=web
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.184.92
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31880/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.4:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

The `kubectl describe ingress example-ingress` gives the following output:

```
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host              Path  Backends
  ----              ----  --------
  hello-world.info
                    /   web:8080   172.17.0.4:8080)
Annotations:        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
Events:             <none>
```

***The issue seems to have been resolved there***, by following the below instructions(as posted in the comments):

> Once you setup the ingress with necessary change, i guess you are in
> the powershell of windows with minikube running right? Make sure you
> ‘enable addons ingress’ and have a separate console running ‘minikube
> tunnel’ as well. Also, add the hostname and ip address to windows’
> host table. Then type ‘minikue ssh’ in powershell, it gives you
> command line. Then you can ‘curl myapp.com’ then you should get
> response as expected.

Nevertheless, in my case, ***the minikube tunnel is not responding upon giving the `minikube tunnel` command.*** :

[image]

***I am not able to `curl hello-world.info` even through `minikube ssh`. Kindly help!***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**On Windows**

After some decent amount of time, I came to the conclusion that ingress has some conflicts to work with Docker on Windows10-Home. Things are working fine if we want to expose a service of NodePort type but Ingress is troublesome.

Further, I tried to set up WSL 2 with Ubuntu in Windows 10 but no luck.

Finally, **the following worked for Ingress of Minikube on Windows10 Home:**

- Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Uncheck the **Virtual Machine Platform** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** options from `Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on and off (under Programs and Features)` and then click ok. Restart your computer if prompted to.
- Now, execute the following commands in a new cmd

```
minikube delete
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

if `minikube start --driver=virtualbox` doesn't work, then use `minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check`.

This process solved my problem and ingress is working fine on my Windows 10 Home Minikube.

**On Ubuntu**

Finally, Docker on Ubuntu is inherently supporting Minikube Ingress seamlessly without any glitch.

Comment: Your answer is one of the best I've ever seen. Thank you for the abundant details!

Answer (score 0):

Same issues here with docker driver.
But everything ok with hyperv driver.
Enable hyperv on your windows and start with: **minikube start --driver=hyperv** or
minikube config set driver hyperv and minikube start