# Minikube dashboard ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

Im trying to make an ingress for the minikube dashboard using the embedded dashboard internal service.

I enabled both `ingress` and `dashboard` minikube addons.

I also wrote this ingress YAML file :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 80
```

My Ingress is being created well as u can see :

```
NAME                CLASS   HOSTS           ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   nginx   dashboard.com   localhost   80      15s
```

I edited my `/etc/hosts` to add this line : `127.0.0.1    dashboard.com`.

Now im trying to access the dashboard trough `dashboard.com`. But it's not working.

`kubectl describe ingress dashboard-ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard` gives me this :

```
Name:             dashboard-ingress
Namespace:        kubernetes-dashboard
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  dashboard.com  
                 /   kubernetes-dashboard:80 (172.17.0.4:9090)
Annotations:     <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    14m (x2 over 14m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

I don't really understand what `<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>` means, but maybe my issue comes from this.

`kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` result :

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create--1-8krc7     0/1     Completed   0          100m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch--1-qblch      0/1     Completed   1          100m
ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-hvk9j   1/1     Running     0          100m
```

Logs for nginx-controller pod :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.0.4
  Build:         9b78b6c197b48116243922170875af4aa752ee59
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W1205 19:33:42.303136       7 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I1205 19:33:42.303261       7 main.go:221] "Creating API client" host="https://10.96.0.1:443"
I1205 19:33:42.319750       7 main.go:265] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="22" git="v1.22.3" state="clean" commit="c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1" platform="linux/amd64"
I1205 19:33:42.402223       7 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I1205 19:33:42.413477       7 ssl.go:531] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I1205 19:33:42.420838       7 nginx.go:253] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I1205 19:33:42.424731       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"f2d27cc7-b103-490f-807f-18ccaa614e6b", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"664", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I1205 19:33:42.427171       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"e174971d-df1c-4826-85d4-194598ab1912", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"665", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services
I1205 19:33:42.427195       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"0ffc7ee9-2435-4005-983d-ed41aac1c9aa", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"666", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services
I1205 19:33:43.622661       7 nginx.go:295] "Starting NGINX process"
I1205 19:33:43.622746       7 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
I1205 19:33:43.623402       7 nginx.go:315] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I1205 19:33:43.623683       7 controller.go:152] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I1205 19:33:43.643547       7 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader
I1205 19:33:43.643635       7 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-hvk9j"
I1205 19:33:43.691342       7 controller.go:169] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I1205 19:33:43.691395       7 controller.go:180] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I1205 19:33:43.691435       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-hvk9j", UID:"55d45c26-eda7-4b37-9b04-5491cde39fd4", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"697", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I1205 21:06:47.402756       7 main.go:101] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I1205 21:06:47.408929       7 store.go:371] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="kubernetes-dashboard/dashboard-ingress" ingressclass="nginx"
I1205 21:06:47.409343       7 controller.go:152] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I1205 21:06:47.409352       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"be1ebfe9-fdb3-4d0c-925b-0c206cd0ece3", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"5529", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I1205 21:06:47.458273       7 controller.go:169] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I1205 21:06:47.458445       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-hvk9j", UID:"55d45c26-eda7-4b37-9b04-5491cde39fd4", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"697", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I1205 21:07:43.654037       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" ingress="dashboard-ingress" currentValue=[] newValue=[{IP: Hostname:localhost Ports:[]}]
I1205 21:07:43.660598       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kubernetes-dashboard", Name:"dashboard-ingress", UID:"be1ebfe9-fdb3-4d0c-925b-0c206cd0ece3", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"5576", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

Anyone has a clue on how i can solve my problem ?

(Im using minikube v1.24.0)

Regards,

Comment: Does any other ingress work for your cluster?

Comment: @Riwen nope :/ im working on a fresh minikube with just dashboard and ingress addons installed + the ingress I talked about in my post

Comment: I'm not familiar with minikube, but I see that the ingress addon adds nginx. Check the logs of the controller pod, `ingress-nginx-controller-(something)`. It should be under the namespace `ingress-nginx`, so try `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` to find it.

Comment: @Riwen the only ingress up on my cluster is the one i defined. I updated my post with the logs. But the two other pods of nginx (ingress-nginx-admission-patch and ingress-nginx-admission-patch) are not running, could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you using Docker under Windows?

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi nope im under Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Maybe if you change Docker driver, use VirtualBox instead.
Latest Minikube versions require VMWare, but this one is not for free. You may use a 30 days trial though.
This may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gip-Q6AWpcY

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi you're right, it works lol. Cant you put this as an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue with minikube(v1.25.1) running in my local.

`kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard`

```
NAME                CLASS   HOSTS           ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   nginx   dashboard.com   localhost   80      34m
```

After  debug I have found this.
"If you are running Minikube locally, use minikube ip to get the external IP. The IP address displayed within the ingress list will be the internal IP".

Run this command

```
minikube ip
XXX.XXX.64.2
```

add this ip in the host file,after that I am able to access dashboard.com

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Minikube's Ingress, but I was using Windows.

After indepth search, I discovered that the problem came from Docker's driver.

I changed the driver to VirtualBox and Ingress started behaving as expected.

This [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901072/could-not-access-minikubev1-18-1-ingress-on-docker-driver-windows-10) provides further details.